# Add special constraint to avoid duplicate rows with this condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unique-constraint

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ClientId  FloorNum   BedNum   IsActive
11        2          212      1        
12        2          214      0        
12        2          214      1        
13        2          215      0        
13        2          215      0        
13        2          215      0        
13        2          215      0        
13        2          215      1        
12        2          215      1
```

As you can see, *FloorNum/BedNum* combination *2/215* has two rows where *IsActive* equals 1. This cannot happen.

On the other hand, one *FloorNum/BedNum* combination can have many rows where *IsActive* equals 0.

How can I add a constraint to a table so that a *FloorNum/BedNum* combination can only have one row where *IsActive* = 1?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of a table are we talking about? Is this Oracle, mySql, or what? And what set of values do you want to be unique? In most relational database systems you simply specify a set of columns to be unique. Such as: alter table myTable add constraint myUniqueConstraint(FloorNum, BedNum, IsActive);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create [a filtered unique index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.100).aspx) with a WHERE clause.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_[index name]_FloorNum_BedNum ON [myTable] (
    FloorNum ASC,
    BedNum ASC)
WHERE (IsActive = 1)
```

This will only take into account records where the `IsActive` column is set to `1`.

Based on your description I think that `ClientId` is not necessary in this example but if I am wrong you can add it to the index as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Trigger` on your table to check this condition.

```
create TRIGGER tr_check_unique ON YourTable
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @FloorNum int;
    declare @BedNum int;

    select @FloorNum=i.FloorNum from inserted i;    
    select @BedNum=i.BedNum from inserted i;    

begin try
        if exists(select FloorNum  ,BedNum  from YourTable
        where FloorNum=@FloorNum and BedNum=@BedNum and IsActive=1)

        raiserror ('',16,1)
end try

begin catch
raiserror ('record is not unique',16,1)
end catch
```

Comment: This will not work if you attempt to insert more than one record at once.